# how to add pinch zoom functionality in flutter qr code scanner?

Tags: flutter

I am developing qr code scanner app using [qr_code_scanner](https://pub.dev/packages/qr_code_scanner) flutter package.I am unable to add the pinch zoom functionality on that. Is there anyway to add this functionality or other qr code scanner package which supports pinch zoom function? Please help me on this.

Answer (score 2):

InteractiveViewer can help you to implement pinch, zoom.
Check this out:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InteractiveViewer-class.html

If you need double tap to zoom, wrap InteractiveViewer with GestureDetector and implement onDoubleTap

```dart
onDoubleTapDown: _handleDoubleTapDown,
              onDoubleTap: () {
                kLogger.i('--> on double tap');
                _handleDoubleTap();
              },
_____

void _handleDoubleTapDown(TapDownDetails details) {
    _doubleTapDetails = details;
}

void _handleDoubleTap() {
    if (_transformationController.value != Matrix4.identity()) {
    _transformationController.value = Matrix4.identity();
} else {
      final position = _doubleTapDetails.localPosition;
      // For a 3x zoom
      _transformationController.value = Matrix4.identity()
        ..translate(-position.dx * 2, -position.dy * 2)
        ..scale(3.0);
      // Fox a 2x zoom
      // ..translate(-position.dx, -position.dy)
      // ..scale(2.0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jimmy. I already tried InteractiveViewer on qrcode scanner but sometimes scanner is getting paused. I used another package flutter_zxing and pinch to zoom works well.

Comment: Hi @arunin25 can you please share the package used for this feature?...Thank you